# Image editor component for use in WPF rich client application

Tags: .net, wpf, image, editor, components

Do you know of a simple .NET component which can be used in a WPF client application with these features:

- load images from file or clipboard into canvas,
- scaling and moving,
- define canvas background color,
- export canvas as new image.

Thx in advance,
Prensen

Comment: Hi if you could find a good could you share it?

Answer (score 2):

What about theese?

http://xdraw.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DrawTools.aspx