# WPF bitmap editor

Tags: c#, wpf, editor, bitmap

Is there any opensource library/WPF Control that can act as bitmap editor (e.g. just like old good MS Paint)? Or some example for starting point?

To be clear — I'm looking for a library (or something), that can be used inside my application.

Any other ideas are wellcome.

Comment: Another question going in the same direction.
(no answer right now)
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537007/image-editor-component-for-use-in-wpf-rich-client-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537007/image-editor-component-for-use-in-wpf-rich-client-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an InkCanvas. It already comes with some built-in features.

Another possibility would be creating your own control based on a WriteableBitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a control to embed in your app or a good, free image editor to create artwork? If it's the later, try [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net).

Comment: Paint.NET is a good (maybe even too good) example of what do I need to embed in my app.
Yes, I'm looking for a control. Sory, I wan't clear enough.