# WPF control for image manipulation

Tags: c#, wpf, image, controls

I need to load an image in a WPF window, an be able to read and modify individual pixels (in an efficient way), zoom the image (and scroll it), get the value RGB/grayscale of the pixel under the cursor, select areas (I guess knowing the cursor position and being able to modify pixels I could draw myself the square which represents the selected area)...

What is the best combination of WPF controls and classes to accomplish this?

I've been trying to do it loading a System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage and putting it into a System.Windows.Controls.Image, but it's taking much longer than I expected.

Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537007/image-editor-component-for-use-in-wpf-rich-client-application

Answer (score 0):

I once used this [WPF Interactive Image Cropping Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20245/WPF-Interactive-Image-Cropping-Control). Go check it out, it should at the very least give you a good place to start. Oh, and welcome to Stackoverflow. :)